# Why do they use reinterpret_cast here?

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, reinterpret-cast

Here's some code from the PhysX examples:

```
std::vector<PxRigidActor*> actors(nbActors);
scene->getActors(PxActorTypeFlag::eRIGID_DYNAMIC | PxActorTypeFlag::eRIGID_STATIC,
                    reinterpret_cast<PxActor**>(&actors[0]), nbActors);
```

And then in the code of the `getActors` function they use it like this:

```
PxU32 NpScene::getActors(PxActorTypeFlags types, PxActor** buffer, PxU32 bufferSize, PxU32 startIndex=0) const
{
   ...
        if ((types & PxActorTypeFlag::eRIGID_STATIC ) && mRigidActors[i]->is<PxRigidStatic>())
        {
            if (virtualIndex >= startIndex)
                buffer[writeCount++] = mRigidActors[i];
            virtualIndex++;
        }
        else if ((types & PxActorTypeFlag::eRIGID_DYNAMIC) && mRigidActors[i]->is<PxRigidDynamic>())
        {
            if (virtualIndex >= startIndex)
                buffer[writeCount++] = mRigidActors[i];
            virtualIndex++;
        }
   ...
}
```

`mRigidActors` is defined as `Ps::Array<PxRigidActor*>`

The inheritance diagram looks like this:

[image: the inheritance diagram showing pxActor is a base of pxRigidActor]

So, my questions are:

1. I heard that the pointer to the parent class can point to the instance of the child class. Then, why do we need any casting at all? I tried, but without casting it doesn't work.
2. Is it safe to use reinterpret_cast as it is used here?
   (I suppose yes, because it's just pointers conversion)
3. Is there a better solution?

Comment: How `PxRigidActor` and `PxActor` are related?

Comment: This is basically reinterpreting `actors.data()` as a `PxActors**` instead of as a `PxRigidActor**`. From the name it sounds like one is derived from the other. It looks likely that `reinterpret_cast` is the wrong cast to use here, as is usually the case when you see `reinterpret_cast`. Edit : The use of `&actors[0]` instead of `actors.data()`, of `reinterpret_cast` and a chain of `if` / `else if` that seems to be checking against every concrete type are all red flags to me, indicating to me that this code should not be taken as a good example.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux What instead? A `static_cast`?

Comment: _inheritance_ should use a hollow triangle arrowhead, pointing the other direction.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram

Comment: I believe that `reinterpret_cast` is used instead of `static_cast` because you can't `static_cast` double pointers as they are never related by inheritance. The explicit cast is used because you can't implicitly perform a `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` was used because it is the only one that will allow the code to compile, but it is an error. You can't fix this code with just a cast, I believe you'll need a second vector with the correct base type to pass to the function, then you would need to cast and copy each element individually to `actors`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I think NVidia is able to get away with it here because they're only using single inheritance. For most, if not all, ABI's, pointer manipulation for a `static_cast` in relation to inheritance is only need when using multiple inheritance. I wouldn't advise most people to exploit this, but given the target audience of PhysX I think this a reasonable tradeoff between safety and performance.

Comment: @vandench Regardless of the ABI, any compiler could break this during optimization. The UB is probably obvious during static analysis (it doesn't seem to depend on runtime information) so a compiler can spot it. And the compiler is allowed to assume UB doesn't occur, so it could optimize the function under the assumption that control never reaches the function call. For example, if the function call is behind an `if` the compiler can assume that `if`'s condition is always `false`. It may work for now, but it can break at any time.

Comment: @vandench I think they get away with it because undefined behaviour *doesn't* imply "loudly breaks"

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I decided to look into whether or not this invoked UB, and AFAICT it doesn't in any major ABI including Win32, Linux, x86, x86-64, ARM, ARM64, and RISC-V. I did a test [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qvGj1qWPK) where no compiler created a warning, and they all reported that strict aliasing wasn't enabled. As it turns out strict aliasing was designed for garbage collectors, and is under [proposal for removal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2186r2.html) because no major ABI's have taken advantage of it.

Comment: @vandench You can't disprove UB by testing against it. The language rules don't allow it, the resulting binaries has nothing to do with it. UB is an abstract concept to be applied to the abstract C++ machine. The purpose of strict aliasing is mainly to allow the compiler to perform better optimizations by reducing the scope of the [aliasing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_(computing)#Conflicts_with_optimization). I guess it is also necessary for garbage collection, but strict aliasing has existed for much longer than the allowance for garbage collection.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Principally, yes, UB is always UB. In practice a lot of what the spec defines (or lack thereof) as UB is quite well defined in their spec. NVidia has a specific target audience and lists the specific systems they support. Additionally, I don't think that this is UB, the spec explicitly states in the final element of the strict aliasing rule (3.7.4.3.4 of publicly accessible N4296 C++2014 draft) that if the compiler chooses to support `relaxed pointer safety` the strict aliasing rules don't matter, the validity of a pointer is independent of whether it was `safely-derived`.

Answer (score 1):

> I heard that the pointer to the parent class can point to the instance of the child class. Then, why do we need any casting at all? I tried, but without casting it doesn't work.

There is an implicit conversion from `PxRigidActor*` to `PxActor*` (a derived-to-base pointer conversion), but there is no such relationship between `PxRigidActor**` and `PxActor**`

> Is it safe to use reinterpret_cast as it is used here? (I suppose yes, because it's just pointers conversion)

The cast is not itself unsafe, but it is undefined behaviour to dereference the pointer created by the cast.

> Is there a better solution?

Define `actors` with an appropriate type in the first place, i.e.

```
std::vector<PxActor*> actors(nbActors);
scene->getActors(PxActorTypeFlag::eRIGID_DYNAMIC | PxActorTypeFlag::eRIGID_STATIC, actors.data(), nbActors);
```

You can then `static_cast<PxRigidActor*>` the elements of `actors` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

`reinterpret_cast<PxActor**>(&actors[0])`
is casting the *address* of the first element of the vector, not casting the element itself.

Furthermore, the called function is treating the pointer as an array.  That is, it is casting the `.data()` of the vector to a different type of element.

You would expect `static_cast` to be used when navigating between base/derived class references *or pointers*.  But that highlights an issue:  The cast might modify the address, if the base class instance is not at the beginning of the derived class!  The `reinterpet_cast` avoids this and just changes the type without changing the value... but if such a value change was necessary, this code would not work right anyway.  By casting the "out" parameter's address instead of the value in that address, the code has no idea that anything stored in that slot needs to be adjusted back to the real type.

Since he's casting a *pointer to* the pointer, the `static_cast` would not work directly in the same place.  It's a double pointer, and that doesn't follow the rule of `D*` to `B*`.  It would have to write the `static_cast`
as a reference cast, and then take the address of *that*.  Off the top of my head, something like `&static_cast<PxActor*&>(actors.data())` (that might have the same issue; I'd have to bang on it to get something working, probably not as a single expression; and I have no intention of trying to do that.)

My guess is that he converted a legacy C cast to `reinterpet_cast` and didn't think too much about it, or saw that only this one worked (in the same place as the legacy cast).

## but why?

The code populates a contiguous collection of the base class pointer.  It takes an `out` parameter instead of returning a `vector`, and the caller wants that vector defined as a derived type instead of the base type.  Normally it should be just fine to keep it as the base class since the behavior is presumably polymorphic.

This is copying from different source collections, with identical code in each branch.  It probably ought to be generic, or use the visitor pattern.  That would avoid most of the type casting issues.

Comment: A C cast is the other thing which I got running but I didn't dare to mention this... :-) [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a608e3cb17cb8e72).

Comment: I'm not sure this actually compiles. Doesn't look like `PxRigidActor**` can be `static_cast` to `PxActor*&`. I'm not sure you can ever cast a reference since `std::vector` only gives you pointers that are rvalues.

Comment: `&static_cast<PxActor*&>(actors.data())` [isn't legal](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dff536244a86f23b)